# Azure Functions - waiting for context.log

Tags: typescript, azure, async-await, azure-functions

I'm seeing a lot of the following when I'm doing a `context.log` in my Azure Function - timed trigger:

> Warning: Unexpected call to 'log' on the context object after function execution has completed. Please check for asynchronous calls that are not awaited or calls to 'done' made before function execution completes

I think it is happening because the return gets called before that `context.log` has fully executed.

But could someone kindly confirm/help explain.

```
export async function onTrigger(context: Context, myTimer: any): Promise<void> {
    async getJobs(context);
}

async function getJobs(context: Context): Promise<void> {
    try {
       const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8111/batches");
       processBatch(context, response);
    } catch (error) {
       context.log.error(`Some Error Log`, error);
    }
}

async function processBatch(context: Context, response: any) {
    //… Some stuff

    if (stableStates.includes(someStatus)) {
       context.log("Some Message")
       return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're mixing `then`/`catch` with `async`. If you use `async`, then use `await`; if you use `then`/`catch`, then don't use `async` and return the promise.

Comment: In addition to @StephenCleary comments you can also wrap the `await` calls with `try`/`catch` to keep the same code flow

Comment: @StephenCleary - I updated my code so that get jobs uses async and now I don't get that error. However could you kindly confirm is that empty return a valid thing to do in this scenario. Is that code example I posted actually 'good code'.

Comment: @userMod2: Yes; the type returned from the method is `Promise<void>`. The `async` keyword creates the `Promise` for you, so your code just has to return the inner type (`void`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code was mixing `then`/`catch` with `async`:

```js
async function getJobs(context: Context): Promise<void> {
  axios
      .get("http://localhost:8111/batches")
      .then(function(response: any) {
        processBatch(context, response);
      })
      .catch(function(error: any) {
        context.log.error(`Some Error Log: `, error);
      });
}
```

The code above (`axios.get(..).then(..).catch(..)`) will create a `Promise`, but that promise is never returned; it's just ignored. Meanwhile, *another* promise is created by `async` that is completed after the first promise is *created* (not completed).

You should use `async`/`await` throughout:

```js
async function getJobs(context: Context): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8111/batches");
    processBatch(context, response);
  } catch (error) {
    context.log.error(`Some Error Log: `, error);
  }  
}
```

Also, you're missing an `await` here:

```js
export async function onTrigger(context: Context, myTimer: any): Promise<void> {
  getJobs(context);
}
```

should be:

```js
export async function onTrigger(context: Context, myTimer: any): Promise<void> {
  await getJobs(context);
}
```